# Identify appropriate exogenous variables for an ARIMA model

Tags: time-series, forecasting, feature-selection, arima

I am forecasting sales data with ARIMA model, I have a bunch of macroeconomic indicators that can be used to identify some of the information present in my sales data.

How do you go about selecting exogenous variables that are most appropriate for running ARIMA?

Comment: This question seems clearly posed to me. Someone has voted to  close as unclear - it would be interesting to know what aspect they feel is ambiguous, so the original poster can clarify if needed

Comment: @Silverfish, I didnt vote down but can see why someone would. It's a very broad subject since there isn't one way of doing this. Even the specification of ARIMA with exogenous variables is not unique, there are different approaches.

Comment: @Aksakal That is fair enough - I could have understood it being closed as "too broad" (though I think this is probably on the limit of acceptability) but I am not so sure about "unclear"

Comment: @Silverfish, agreed, it seemed clear what was asked, it's a typical variable /model selection problem.

Comment: Given the upvoted answer, I think this question is clear enough to be answerable. I'm voting to leave open.

Comment: this thread comes to mind: http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/

Comment: This is my first question in cross validated, I tried to stick to the guidelines as much as I could have. however, kindly do let me know how you would have phrased this question?
Or, this question is way to broad to be a part of cross validated forum?

Before asking this, I actually googled a lot and even looked at hyndman's blog, however I did not find anything.

Answer (score 4):

One way to do ARIMA with exogenous variables would be [ARIMAX](https://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/arima-model-including-exogenous-regressors.html). The variable selection process would be quite similar to other regressions. For in-sample you could compare AIC/BIC, for out-of-sample it's some version of root mean sqaured forecast error (RMSE). This could be one step ahead or multiple steps ahead. Usual parsimony and autocorrelation concerns are used etc. With time series you must be worried about cointegration and stationarity to avoid spurious regressions.

The bottom line is that there is no standard procedure, it depends on your preferences. You create a bunch of specifications then compare their diagnostics.

Comment: Thanks @Aksakal

So lets say i have 2 regressors and i am following out of sample method.
Then In that case, something I can do is run ARIMA with first and second regressor independently, another ARIMA with both in them, compare the RMSE, MAPE etc of all three models?

will doing this make sense?

i understood that ARIMA is more like try and error, improve-the-existing-model kind of thing.

There is no hard and fast rule for model selection :|

Comment: YEs, you can do what you described. As I wrote earlier in time series there are things to worry about in addition to forecasting performance metrics such as MAPE. More over, in time series such as ARIMA the error terms are different for different forecasting horizons. FOr instance, a random walk model has increasing error (by square root of horizon). Therefore, it's meaning less to average MAPE over horizon. You must look at short term and long term forecast performance separately